# Changing existing organization to be backed up by Azure Active Directory

Tags: azure-devops

I have an organization created within Azure-devops (previously VSTS). I want to change its organization to be backed up by Azure Active Directory.

How can i achieve this?. I have admin rights over it.

Comment: You can find a walkthrough here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/connect-organization-to-azure-ad?view=vsts&tabs=new-nav

Comment: Thank you. Taking your response as approved. Regards.